# VBA Count cells in column containing specified value

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a macro that searches a specified column and counts all the cells that contain a specified string, such as **`"19/12/11" or "Green"`** then associate this number with a variable,

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Do you mean you want to use a formula in VBA? Something like:

```
Dim iVal As Integer
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Range("A1:A10"),"Green")
```

should work.

Comment: By the way, you can add wildcards to your search string like this: `iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Range("A1:A10"),"*Green*")`

Answer (score 15):

This isn't *exactly* what you are looking for but here is how I've approached this problem in the past;

You can enter a formula like;

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Green")
```

...into a cell. This will count the Number of cells between A1 and A10 that contain the text "Green". You can then select this cell value in a VBA Macro and assign it to a variable as normal.

Comment: Your answer desserves a +1 for giving the right way to follow. And I hope this will encourage you to keep on answering other questions

Comment: Good answer thank you, shown a different way I can go about it

Answer (score 2):

one way;

```
var = count("find me", Range("A1:A100"))

function count(find as string, lookin as range) As Long
   dim cell As Range
   for each cell in lookin
       if (cell.Value = find) then count = count + 1 '//case sens
   next
end function
```

Comment: Works - but will be very slow on decent sized ranges to test cell by cell, better to use a function like JMax did, or use the range `Find` method

Comment: Works, and is great thanks, but as above JMax's method seems to work better for me

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to match non-blank values or empty cells and having difficulty with wildcard character, I found the solution below from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/use-vba-to-count-non-blank-cells-in-a-column.32797/).

```
Dim n as Integer
n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked but may be useful nevertheless.

Of course you can do the same thing with matrix formulas.
Just read the result of the cell that contains:

`Cell A1="Text to search"`
`Cells A2:C20=Range to search for`

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(A1;A2:C20;1))
```

Remember that entering matrix formulas needs CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, not just ENTER.
After, it should look like :

`{=COUNT(SEARCH(A1;A2:C20;1))}`

Comment: bummi ... Wouldn't it be cool if someone that does a negative evaluation tells why ? So that next time, I wont make the same mistake ? I know I'm a newbie, so I could be wrong ...

Comment: I'm not the person who voted this down, but my guess is that the question started out "I need to write a macro" and it had "VBA" at the beginning of the title, but your answer is actually a worksheet function. I, too, find it annoying to see downvotes with no explanation.