# VBA count how many times a text appear on a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

is there a way to count how many times a text appear on a worksheet?

im sorry about my question but I don't know how to start.

thanks.

Comment: What about doing some quick research? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592915/vba-count-cells-in-column-containing-specified-value

Comment: @varocarbas That question you linked has nothing to do with this.  That only looks within a specific range for a cell that has an exact value.  The question here is open ended asking to find text in a **worksheet** and they do not specify if it is with other text or just by itself.

Comment: @ObieMD5 are you telling me that a spreadsheet is not a range? What is it then and how you access its contents? I thought that it was enough by replacing the part in this link referring to column range with the worksheet range, but apparently I am wrong. Please, could you explain me the exact difference?

Comment: @Erin Santos, logically, I am being sarcastic: please replace the column range with the worksheet range in the link above (and next time better spend 1 minute doing research before asking: 30 seconds to find this link and another 30 seconds to understand how to use this link with a worksheet).

Comment: You could also give a few more details. For example, do you care about textboxes? Or, if you're looking for "Erin" and a cell contain "Erin Santos" should we count it? If it contains "ErinErin" should we count it twice? Please get in the habit of providing some detail to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the short answer is "Yes"

Here are a few ways:

in cell A1 put the following formula:

=COUNTIF(2:1048576,"here") + COUNTIF(B1:XFD1,"here")

this will count the number of times "here" appears on the worksheet

if you'd like to use vba, this should return the expected result:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wordCount As Long

    wordCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Cells, "here")

End Sub
```

I'm sure there are a handful of other ways to go about it, but hopefully this will get you started.

The longer answer is (as mentioned in the comments): Please be a bit more descriptive in your ask so someone can tailor an answer to fit your specific requirements.  That, or google it.