# Can I make subtotal macro more efficient?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where data is pasted in the format below. I need to count the number of times there is an entry in each month, as you can see from the example below it can occur on many days within the month.

The only way I can think of to do it is to separate the month out and to subtotal it and copy the totals.

Trouble is that it is taking ages to run due to the amount on data.

Is there another way of going about it that I'm not seeing? I've pasted my current code below. TIA

[image]

```
' Add Totals

Sheets("Data").Select
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "mm"
Range("F4").Select
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=7, Function:=xlCount, TotalList:=Array(7), _
    Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
Range("G3:G4000").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Set Up Data").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("D56").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.RemoveSubtotal
```

Comment: Did either of the answers below work for you? If so please mark as one as correct. It is something only the person posing the question can do. Click on the green check mark by the one that is correct, the one you used.

Answer (score 2):

It will be faster to copy the data to a variant array, and do the analysis on that.

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Counts(1 To 12, 1 To 1) As Long

    ' Get range reference to source data
    '   assumes data is in column G, starting at row 4.  Adjust as required
    With Worksheets("Data")
        Set rData = .Range(.Cells(4, 7), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))
    End With

    ' copy range data to variant array
    vData = rData.Value

    ' count occurance of each month
    For i = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
        ' allow for possibility that dates are actually strings
        Counts(Month(CDate(vData(i, 1))), 1) = Counts(Month(CDate(vData(i, 1))), 1) + 1

    Next

    ' put count data back on sheet
    '   adjust target as required
    Worksheets("Set Up Data").Cells(2, 2).Resize(UBound(Counts, 1), 1) = Counts

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch on this line -  Counts(Month(vData(i, 1)), 1) = Counts(Month(vData(i, 1)), 1) + 1

Comment: Are your "Dates" actually dates, or strings that _look_ like dates? If they are, see updated code

Comment: My original code works fine for me with the dates as Date Serial Numbers, formatted to display as dates.  The revised version version will work with either date serial numbers or strings.  If it still doesn't work for you then something else not contained in your post is going on. I would need to see a sample workbook to help diagnose further

Comment: Still getting type mismatch. I've even changed the format on the column to check that it's dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm and it still happens. I am intrigued a to why it's not working??? I've saved the worksheet here - 

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?page=view&resid=6B478A9537E4D0F3!2618&authkey=!AIlbZvgRiY2v6eM

Comment: The reason you get errors is that there is invalid date data starting at row 2454 - `30/11/-0001 00:00:00`.  Fix that and my code works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101582/discussion-between-hazel-popham-and-chris-neilsen).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 other ways I can think of but both will show the answers in a different table:

1. Use a pivot table
2. Use PowerQuery - this is now built-in to Excel 2016 but is a free Microsoft addin for 2010/2013.

Comment: This is a calculation needed in the middle of a macro I'm afraid so can't use these.

Comment: @HazelPopham Why can't you create a pivot table, grab the results, then delete it - just as your original code tries to do with the subtotals?

Comment: I didn't know you could create pivot tables via a macro?

Comment: You could do something similar with PowerQuery though in that case, you would need to have the query set up. Simply refresh it using a macro as desired. You can output from PQ direct to the data model too so you don't need to have the output on a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but should be faster than what you have. I assume you know the minimum date and the maximum date.

You start by adding a new column that concatenates the month and the year. For instance, for January 24 2016, the column value would be January2016. You loop through the sheet to add this column for each row. Now you do a second loop and this time loop through dates between the start month and the end month and in the loop you count the number of occurrences of each concatenated string in the sheet's column of month-years strings. So if the first month is February 2015, you count the number of occurrences of February2015 in the column and then next iteration you count the number of March2015 and so on. At the end, you have the count by month and you delete the extra column.

Comment: That sounds really clever - but it's a bit beyond my capabilities I'm afraid!

Comment: The first part is doing the extra column: just set the cell value to be equal to the month + year of the date. See this: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/month.php And once you've got this, all you need is the count for each month of the loop, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592915/vba-count-cells-in-column-containing-specified-value

Answer (score 0):

You could always go the formula method:

[image]

With the table set up I used the COUNTIF() formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(G:G,"<"&DATE(K2,J2+1,1),G:G,">=" &DATE(K2,J2,1))
```

Or you could use the SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G:G<DATE(K2,J2+1,1))*(G:G>=DATE(K2,J2,1)))
```

This is just an FYI.

Comment: If formula was acceptable, better one is `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(G:G)=J2)*(G:G<>""))` (or `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(G:G)=J2)*(YEAR(G:G)=K2)*(G:G<>""))` if year test is reqd)

Comment: @chrisneilsen  I may be wrong but I do not think you can use Month or Year in an array like that, I did try yours and it came back as #VALUE.  To use the sumproduct it would need to be: `=SUMPRODUCT((G:G<DATE(K2,J2+1,1))*(G:G>=DATE(K2,J2,1)))` which is now almost the same as countifs()

Comment: @chrisnelson I wonder what I am doing wrong. I will play with it.

Answer (score -1):

Please, can you try the following code? I have just changed a few things from what you posted. Data must be sorted by join date for it to work.

```
Sub testSubtotal()
  Sheets("Data").Select
  Columns("G:G").Select
  ' Since you have two different years in the example I think it would be
  ' better to get subtotals for year and month together
  Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm"
  Range("F1").Select
  Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=7, Function:=xlCount, TotalList:=Array(7), _
      Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
  ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

  ' Selecting also column F you will get the description of the subtotal
  ' in the "Set Up Data" worksheet
  Range("F1:G4000").Select
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
  Sheets("Set Up Data").Select

  ' I have changed the destination cell to B1
  ' but I do not know how yor worksheet is formatted.
  Range("B1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Sheets("Data").Select
  Cells.Select
  Selection.RemoveSubtotal
End Sub
```

I have only tested it on a table with few data, but it does not seem to be slow. I just hope I understood correctly your question...

Comment: Work fine but is still slow on the amount of data I have.